# using useConext to change state of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import PermIdentityOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PermIdentityOutlined";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined";
import "./Register.css";

const UserContext = createContext({});

function UserContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const [id, setId] = useState(null);
  return <UserContext.Provider value={{ name, setName, id, setId }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
}

const Register = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPasssword] = useState("");
  const { setName, setId } = useContext(UserContext);
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    await axios.post("/register", { username, password }).then((data) => {
      setName(username);

      setId(data.id);
    });
  }
};
```

When i am calling the 'setName',  it is giving error 'setName is not function'

i am trying to store 'username' in 'name' variable using 'setName' function

Comment: You're not showing whether you're wrapping your `<Register>` in an `UserContextProvider` at all.

Comment: @AKX O mais provável é que não esteja a ser incluído num UserContextProvider

Comment: You are not using use context correctly maybe checking out [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) might help

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 3 things:

1. Create a separate file for your context:

```js
import { createContext, useState } from 'react'
const UserContext = createContext({})

function UserContextProvider({ children }) {
    const [name, setName] = useState(null)
    const [id, setId] = useState(null)
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ name, setName, id, setId }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { UserContext, UserContextProvider }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

2. Import the UserContext into your Register.jsx file:

   ```js
   import React from 'react'
   import axios from 'axios'
   import { useContext } from 'react'
   import { useState } from 'react'
   import PermIdentityOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PermIdentityOutlined'
   import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined'
   import './Register.css'
   import { UserContext } from '../fullPathHere/UserContext.jsx'

   const Register = () => {
       const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
       const [password, setPasssword] = useState('')
       const { setName, setId } = useContext(UserContext)
       async function handleSubmit(e) {
           e.preventDefault()

           await axios.post('/register', { username, password }).then((data) => {
               setName(username)

               setId(data.id)
           })
       }
   }

   export default Register
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   ```
3. Import the UserContextProvider and place the Register.jsx wrapped in the UserContextProvider tag:

```js
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import UserContextProvider from './fullPathHere/UserContext.jsx'
import Register from './fullPathHere/Register.jsx'

function App(props) {
    return (
        <UserContextProvider>
            <Register />
        </UserContextProvider>
    )
}

export default App
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```